# Raw string encoding from input()

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, directory

I'm trying to scan a variable directory, said variable is defined by an `input()`, yet the program throws out this issue:
`(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 320-321: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

Current code: **Not Working**

```
import os
import time

print("Enter directory name.\nDirectory name example:\nC:\Users\example\Documents")

dirname = input()

with os.scandir(dirname) as dir_entries:
    for entry in dir_entries:
        info = entry.stat()
        file_name = os.path.basename(entry)

        my_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(info.st_ctime))
        rawmb = (info.st_size/(1024*1024))
        truncated = round(rawmb, 3)

        print(file_name)
        print(my_time)
        print(truncated,"MB")
        print('===========================')
```

I considered using `\\` or `/` instead of `\` during the input, but that makes copying the directory from the file explorer impossible.

I have no idea how to include an `r` in front of the `input()` string.

`.decode`,`.encode` didn't seem to work for me either, but I most likely just used them wrong.

---

Edit #1
Tried the solution from J_H

> Do this after input(): for ch in dirname: print(ch, ord(ch))

Result:
Same error.

---

Comment: Do this after input(): `for ch in dirname: print(ch, ord(ch))`. That will help you figure out "\"  backwhack details. We are looking for **single** versus **double** backwhack. Edit your question to share that with us.  Also, hardcode a known-working parent directory in the program, and let input() choose a child or grandchild directory beneath that. After seeing successes and failures that way, you will come to a better understanding of what's happening. Presumably this code works fine with an `r"some_dir"` hardcode, and it's strictly the input() detail that is causing trouble?

Comment: > Presumably this code works fine with an r"some_dir" hardcode, and it's strictly the input() detail that is causing trouble?

Correct, it works just fine if hardcoded.

Comment: You seem to be having trouble with `str` file paths. Consider using `from pathlib import Path`, and working with paths. You can even do `directory = Path("some_dir")` and then ask about all the `directory.glob("*.txt")` files within it.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] rules: *Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it.* Then you know that received error message comes from `print`.  Solution: `print("Enter directory name.\nDirectory name example:\n" +  r"C:\Users\example\Documents")`